# unable to rosmake ccny_rgbd package

Tags: ros, ccny-rgbd, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

following error occurred
-- Searching for g2o ...
CMake Error at cmake-modules/FindG2O.cmake:93 (message):
Could not find libg2o!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165861/unable-to-rosmake-ccny_rgbd-package/) by [hgtc-dp](https://answers.ros.org/users/15556/hgtc-dp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the instructions of ccny_rgbd ros wiki page,

please make sure that all dependencies are installed using 'rosdep'

One has to first remove the remove the libg2o if its already present.

ccny_rgbd stack comes with ccny_g2o package that will be used for the optimization

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0